# Why are my C structure declarations not being recognized?

Tags: c, pointers, gnu, calloc

I am developing a TIN model application and have a structure 'Vertex' that I have defined in the common area at the top of my C program.

```
struct Vertex
{
    int GblSeqNum;
    int PlySeqNum;
    struct Polyline *Line;
    double CtrZ;
    double x;
    double y; 
    double z;
    struct Edge *OwnerEdge;
    struct Vertex *NextVtx;
    struct Vertex *PrevVtx;
};
```

Next, right below the Vertex structure, I declare a global pointer to a Vertex structure:

```
struct Vertex *VtxsInLines;
```

Then, still in the common area, I use calloc to assign space for my vertices:

```
VtxsInLines = (struct Vertex *)(calloc(15000, sizeof(struct Vertex)));
```

I compile the code using GNU C compiler using MinGW on Windows 10:

```
C:\000WORKIndexedTasks 000-999\500 Papers\523 PositionalAccuracyContourLines>gcc -c 523*.c
```

The following warnings and errors are generated:

```
523Paper_ReadContourVertices.c:98:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 VtxsInLines = (struct Vertex *)(calloc(15000, sizeof(struct Vertex)));
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
523Paper_ReadContourVertices.c:98:1: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'VtxsInLines' [-Wimplicit-int]
523Paper_ReadContourVertices.c:98:1: error: conflicting types for 'VtxsInLines'
523Paper_ReadContourVertices.c:47:16: note: previous declaration of 'VtxsInLines' was here

    struct Vertex *VtxsInLines;
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
523Paper_ReadContourVertices.c:98:15: warning: initialization of 'int' from 'struct Vertex *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 VtxsInLines = (struct Vertex *)(calloc(15000, sizeof(struct Vertex)));
```

It appears my declarations are in error somehow and this leads the compiler to assume an int type.  This generates lots of errors later such as:

```
523Paper_ReadContourVertices.c: In function 'main':

523Paper_ReadContourVertices.c:432:20: error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int')
   

    (VtxsInLines+idx)->GblSeqNum = -1;
```

Can you tell me with what what I provided what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't describe what you do but show the related code instead. Copy&paste it as formatted text into the question (no screenshots etc.). Also what does "in the common area" mean? At file scope outside of any function?

Comment: When you want to use members of the `Vertex` structure, or if you need its size, you must have the full structure definition, i.e. include the header file where you define it. A forward declaration of the structure isn't enough.

Comment: It seems that you want to do that assignment on file scope which is not allowed. Only declarations and definitions are allowed at file scope. You can defin a variable and initialize it but that does not allow function calls as you do. The compiler takes your assignment as a new definition. In absence of a type `int` is assumed. Hence the error in `main`.-

Comment: I will declare my structures in a header file and include it to see the effect.

Comment: You can use the `edit` button below your question to add the missing code.

Comment: Perhaps we should have started with this: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a **[mre]**. The small amount of code you show isn't really enough for us to be able to replicate the problem ourselves, or to be able to reliably help you without a lot of guessing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are allocating the `Vertex` structure in the global space. It is not permissible to run executable instructions in the global scope, only allowed in functions such as `main`. The fix would be to move the `VtxsInLines = (struct Vertex *)(calloc(15000, sizeof(struct Vertex)));` statement into the `main` function. You would still be able to access the memory assigned to the `VtxsInLines` variable in other functions without having to pass it along because `VtxsInLines` is global.

Comment: Others pointed this out, but your response was much clearer/  Thanks for your thoughtful advice.  I tried it and it worked!